# Java: How to write generic function that accepts Enum constants that implement a given interface?

Tags: java, generics, enums, type-safety, enumset

So i have a bunch of enum's that all extend an interface:

```
public interface MyInterface {}
```

I then have several enums that extend the interface:

```
public enum A implements MyInterface {}

public enum B implements MyInterface {}
```

I want a function that will accept only enum's that extend this interface.  I cannot do:

```
public void MyFunction(MyInterface input)
```

because, inside the function, I create an EnumSet using EnumSet.of(input).  I cannod do

```
public <T extends Enum<T>> void myFunction(T input)
```

because, inside the function, I need to create a Map that needs to be passed to another function.  So is there any type-safe way to do this w/o casting?

Edit: Corrected interface definitions.

Comment: That should be `enum A implements MyInterface`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can give multiple bounds to your type parameter:

```
public <T extends Enum<T> & MyInterface> void myFunction(T input)
```

Note: You're missing return type of the method. I've given `void` here. Change accordingly. Oh! And please follow Java naming conventions. Method name should start with lowercase letters.